# add background color to td

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a table in html5 using css3, this table has the functionality that when clicking a record the full row is selected so that the user can see which register is selected and works perfectly, but I tried to put a vertical scrollbar by adding it A few styles in css when selecting the row does not add the background color property. These are the css properties that do not allow the background color to be displayed:

```
 .table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
  }
  .table-fixed tbody {
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
    display: block;
  }
  .table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr> th {
    float: left;
    border-bottom-width: 0;

  }
```

this is the full code:

```js
$("#table tr").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px #DDD solid;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #18a7ec !important;
  color: #FFF;
}

.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}

.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}

.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed thead>tr>th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabla" class="col-md-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>
            Fixed Header Scrolling Table
          </h4>
        </div>
        <table id="table" class="table table-fixed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="col-xs-2">#Visita</th>
              <th class="col-xs-3">Código</th>
              <th class="col-xs-4">Cliente</th>
              <th class="col-xs-3">Inicio</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="datos">
            <tr>

              <td class="col-xs-2">1111</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">1111</td>
              <td class="col-xs-4">1111</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">1111</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="col-xs-2">2222</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">2222</td>
              <td class="col-xs-4">2222</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">2222</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td class="col-xs-2">3333</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">3333</td>
              <td class="col-xs-4">3333</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">3333</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of floatting elements, the parent doesn't expand .`color` and `background` is applied, but `tr` has no height to show the `background`, that's why you do not see it.

`overflow:hidden` is one way to reset the [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) , [clearing floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

```js
$("#table tr").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px #DDD solid;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #18a7ec !important;
  color: #FFF;
}

.table-fixed thead {
  width: 97%;
}

.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
  }
  tr {
  overflow:hidden;
}

.table-fixed tbody td,
.table-fixed thead>tr>th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabla" class="col-md-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4>
            Fixed Header Scrolling Table
          </h4>
        </div>
        <table id="table" class="table table-fixed">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="col-xs-2">#Visita</th>
              <th class="col-xs-3">Código</th>
              <th class="col-xs-4">Cliente</th>
              <th class="col-xs-3">Inicio</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="datos">
            <tr>

              <td class="col-xs-2">1111</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">1111</td>
              <td class="col-xs-4">1111</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">1111</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

              <td class="col-xs-2">2222</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">2222</td>
              <td class="col-xs-4">2222</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">2222</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>

              <td class="col-xs-2">3333</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">3333</td>
              <td class="col-xs-4">3333</td>
              <td class="col-xs-3">3333</td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: nice references about the float's and the problems when using them

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, now it works perfect, excellent.